# CSS divs overlapping

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I got an image which is half faded out and when you hover over it, it will fade into the screen. I also have a box which i made so when you hover over that it will change color. However the problem is if i make the box go around the image the only thing that works is the box changing color,  so its overlapping the other image. Anyway to fix this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="eng" lang="eng">
<head>

<style>
.meh
{
    position: relative; 
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: -550px;
    left: 740px;

}

.meh:hover
{
    opacity:1.2;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
}

.border
{
    position: relative; 
    height: 200px; 
        width:  200px; 
        border: 1px solid black;  
        text-align:center; 
    top: -650px;
}

.border:hover
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
    </style>


</head>
<body>

<div class="meh">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="meh">
</div>


<div class="border">    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle to give us a clearer example? I copied your code into one and there doesn't seem to be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there top: -550px; values are given??

I have removed those values here.

**Method - 1** (to get the hover effect for the entire divs)

```
.meh
{
    position: relative; 
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
}
.meh:hover
{
    opacity:1.2;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
}
.border
{
    position: relative; 
    height: 200px; 
        width:  200px; 
        border: 1px solid black;  
        text-align:center;     
}
.border:hover
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ARFpj/1/)**

---

**Method - 2**  (To give separate hover effect for both the div )

Just add display:inline to `.meh`

```
.meh
{
    position: relative; 
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; display:inline
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ARFpj/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Let me try...

```
    <style>
    .meh
    {
        z-index: 500;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px; 
        text-align: center; 
    }
    .meh img {
        margin-top: 50px;
        opacity:0.5;
        filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
    }
    .meh img:hover {
        opacity:1.2;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
    }   
    .border {
        z-index: -1;
        background: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 200px; 
                width:  200px; 
        border: 1px solid black;  
    }

    .border:hover{
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
        </style>
```

I don't know if this is the style you are trying to achieved. I've changed your css since your approach is to perform the ":hover" selector on the elements image and div.box. I haven't really tried performing in css two hovers at the same time. I would suggest you do it on jquery or javascript if you'd like.

You can try this out and comment your css.